# xpage: document1 is not defined

Tags: xpages

In the source of an xpage I have, RIGHT after the opening view tag...the following:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument
        formName="myform"
        var="document1"
    </xp:this.data>
```

I need to be able to pull the value of any field for various functions.   In a 'Server JavaScript' library I have this function, as a test:

```
function testThis(){
    debugger;
    var mystring = document1.getElementById("#{id:employeeTitle}");
    console.log(mystring);
```

(...expecting everything in the element to be logged in the console.)

You can see I have the XPage bound to a DominoDocument with the variable name of 'document1'.

The function is called via a button, and stops for the debugger...so I can step through it.

In Firefox debugger, it is 'Paused at an exception' that says:

```
ReferenceError: document1 is not defined
```

I am sure this is something simple staring right at me, but I just don't get it.   Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Quick comment: you are mixing the server side document1 variable with client side JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up ServerSide JS and client side. The Firefox debugger only knows about client side debugging (which is code that executes in the browser). For debugging server side JS I suggest the Debug Toolbar plugin that you can find at open NTF.https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar

You can also write to the server log with _dump, see https://xcellerant.net/2014/10/15/using_dump_to_write_to_server_console/

Finally, note in your code that if SSJS, you would use document1.getItemValueString("whatever") to access document values. The document object is of type NotesXSPDocument. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/reference/r_wpdr_xsp_xspdocument_r.html

Comment: Thank you Howard..I have a mental block it seems when determining the difference (when CSJS or SSJS is appropriate for any given situation). I actually think here what I am WANTING to do is get information from a field via CSJS for purposes such as hiding an element in real time during an onchange event or for validating all fields upon submit of a page.  I think you may have put me on a good path by your comments.

Comment: Matt, if you want the value in CSJS see Knut's comment above on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Howard, I tried, and have added a comment to his answer...I have something messed up, it's driving me nuts.  Just to clarify, this is on a form (XPage) that is being composed, not edited....I cannot see how that would make a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

You get the DOM element of the rendered field `employeeTitle` on client side in your CSJS code with

```
var element = document.getElementById("#{id:employeeTitle}");
```

and the content value with [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Use **document** (entry point to web page loaded in the browser) instead of **document1** (usually named XPage's data source on server side).

Your function testThis() has to be a part of the XPage, Custom Control or a SSJS library. This makes sure that `#{id:employeeTitle}` gets replaced with the real DOM id **on server** during rendering. If you want to put testThis() into a CSJS library you have to deliver the id as parameter to the function like

```
function testThis(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    ...
```

and call the function in XPage like

```
testThis("#{id:employeeTitle}");
```

Comment: Knut,

Thank you for trying, but I am getting "element is null" with the line: document.getElementById("#{id:employeeTitle}");....this should not be this difficult I know.

Comment: Matt, please update your question with the exact location of your client side JS code. Is it on the XPage itself or in separate file? Thanks.

Comment: I extended my answer and hope you get it to run now.

Comment: Hey guys....really appreciate your efforts.   Per Henrik....it WAS in a library, but now I have a little bit of dedicated script directly next to the field and it is working....seems like it was not lying to me, the DOM element was actually null when I was trying to get a handle on it, which totally confuses me. This is an action happening via the onchange event of a combobox.   How can the element be null if I have already been filling out the form?    I probably need to go to an "web page events 101" class to understand the nuance here.

Knut....gonna reply to you in a separate comment

Comment: Knut..guess you cannot get verbose here....was running out of characters.    I have not tried your suggestion (in your edited answer) since I got something working.  It seem incredible to me that XPages does not have an easier way to get values from fields via the client side.  They gave us all these nice things like currentDocument, global database variable, etc, but not a simple function for a CLIENT version of getitemValueString().    Maybe jQuery is a possible solution for me.

Hope you are doing well...we worked briefly together when I was at GBS and you visited (brought gummy bears)

Comment: Hey Matt, nice to "see" you here. Hope you are doing well. I think putting the code direct into the XPage was the solution as #{id:...} does not get replaced with the real DOM id in a  CSJS library.